# VBA Json converter not converting more than 15 digits

Tags: json, vba, excel

Im using the VBA JSON Converter from this link https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON

I have a cell that has a 16 digit number, however when I convert it to JSON, it converts it without the quotes.

So it suppose to be like this

```
{
    ID: "1525879763214789"
}
```

but shows up like this

```
{
   ID: 1525879763214789
}
```

I tried changing the cell format to text but that does not help either

Edit:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
Dim z As Integer, items As New Collection, myitem As New Dictionary
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Variant
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim JsonTS As TextStream
Set JsonTS = FSO.OpenTextFile("test.json", ForReading)
JsonText = JsonTS.ReadAll
JsonTS.Close
Set JSON = ParseJson(JsonText)

JSON("root")(1)("STATUS_RESPONSE")("RESULT")(1)("USER")("BUSINESS_ID") = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 1).Value
JSON("root")(1)("STATUS_RESPONSE")("RESULT")(1)("USER")("ID") = Sheets(1).Cells(2, 2).Value

myfile = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\test.json"
Open myfile For Output As #1
Print #1, ConvertToJson(JSON, Whitespace:=2)
MsgBox ("Exported to JSON file")
Close #1

End Sub
```

My JSON

```
{
    "root": [{
        "STATUS_RESPONSE": {
            "STATUS": {
                "STATUS": {
                    "OWNER": "root"
                }
            },
            "REQ_ID": "00000",
            "RESULT": [{
                "USER": {
                    "BUSINESS_ID": "A",
                    "USER_NUMBER": "45",
                    "LANGUAGE": "F",
                    "ID" : "1525879763214789"
                }
            },
            {
                "USER_SESSION": {
                    "USER_ID": "0000001009",
                    "HELP_URL": "http://google.com"
                }
            },
            {
                "USER_ACCESS": {
                    "SERVICES_ROLE": "true",
                    "JOURNALLING": "true"

                }
            }]
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Added my code and JSON

Comment: Are the "" present in the cell?  You can do  Chr$(34) & CDec(Cells(2, 2).Value) & Chr$(34) . If I have the number in a cell this results in "1525879763214780"

Comment: No they are not, if you keep the format as text it appears as the number but when converting back to json it removes the quotes

Comment: @QHarr also the code snippet doesn't work because it appear as two double quotes in the JSON

Comment: Yeah basically, with what I'm doing I get no quotes, with what ur doing I get double quotes

Comment: if it's a number, why do you want it in quotes? Quotes are for strings, not numbers. They're different data types. IMO the json converter is doing its job correctly.

Comment: The way I use this json file, it has to be in quotes

Comment: But you are saying that a 15 digit number is fine?

Comment: Yes 15 digit is fine

Comment: "The way I use this json file, it has to be in quotes"...then I would consider using it differently. Numbers and strings are not the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the section of code below, set the flag for `UseDoubleForLargeNumbers` to True and that should work.

```
Dim myfile As Variant
myfile = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path & "C:\Temp\test_out.json"
Open myfile For Output As #1

JsonConverter.JsonOptions.UseDoubleForLargeNumbers = True

Print #1, ConvertToJson(JSON, Whitespace:=2)
'MsgBox ("Exported to JSON file")
Close #1
```

Comment: In the module `JsonConverter` that you had to import into your project, you can go into that code and read all of it. In the header section there is a private type called `json_Options`. Within that definition, there is a comment that says `By default, VBA-JSON will use String for numbers longer than 15 characters that contain only digits, to override set JsonConverter.JsonOptions.UseDoubleForLargeNumbers = True`